# Is there a particular name for a'long-small-small' tensor/array?

Tags: matrices, terminology, tensors

I'm thinking of a 3D array, with dimensions small,small,large.

I've taken to saying 'sausage' as shorthand (and I'm sure there are worse NSFW descriptions) but is there a 'legitimate' description for this kind of arrangement?

Comment: I don't believe anybody's taken the time to name tensors with special dimensions...

Comment: Sausage it is then :D

Comment: It reminds me of a [prolate spheroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroid), but I'm really reaching here. (Plus, it would only be technically correct if both short dimensions were equal.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no established term for these kinds of arrays.